# Android wear watch face debugging on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

Every time I run the watch face to debug on an emulator with android studio, the watch face would change to the default and then I manually need to hold down and select the watch face I'm developing.

It wasn't always like that I would run the watch face and see the changes right away.

I can't figure out why it's happening, the only clue I have is this stack trace:

```
04-14 21:45:42.591 1299-1659/system_process W/ActivityManager: Spurious death for ProcessRecord{ea14c9e 0:com.thexabyte.dscore/u0a25}, curProc for 31189: null
04-14 21:45:42.591 1299-1312/system_process W/WallpaperManagerService: Wallpaper uninstalled, removing: ComponentInfo{com.thexabyte.dscore/com.thexabyte.dscore.AbacusWatchFace}
04-14 21:45:42.605 1299-1318/system_process W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
                                                              android.os.DeadObjectException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
    at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStarted(IWindow.java:520)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:282)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
    at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

[image]

Comment: Which emulator image are you using? (CPU, API level, etc.)

Comment: I added a screenshot with the details, I'm going to play around with these settings to see if it helps, thanks for the hint!